# How do i skip a element from a list

Tags: python, image, selenium, web

I try to find out how to add a image id to a list and skip it in the next search.
That is my code so far, i tried a lot out... the bot should always add the image that he copy recently to the 'used' blacklist and dont copy it next time.

```
search = True
used = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://9gag.com/funny')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value='//*[@id="qc-cmp2-ui"]/div[2]/div/button[1]/span').click()
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    while search:

        post = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='.post-container a img')
        if post.id in used:
            search = True
        else:
            search = False



    post_url = post.get_attribute('src')
    post_title = post.get_attribute('alt')
    used.append(post.id)
    print(post_url)
    print(post_title)
    print('......')
    print(used)
    print(post.id)
    time.sleep(20)
```

The problem: He add the used image to the list but he still find and copy it...

```
https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aWgNx36_460s.jpg
Fat acceptance activist on the news was so fat they had to put her in landscape mode
......
['4d17ee3f-213a-4d54-a18f-425f8f4dea4b']
4d17ee3f-213a-4d54-a18f-425f8f4dea4b
https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aWgNx36_460s.jpg
Fat acceptance activist on the news was so fat they had to put her in landscape mode
......
['4d17ee3f-213a-4d54-a18f-425f8f4dea4b', '4d17ee3f-213a-4d54-a18f-425f8f4dea4b']
4d17ee3f-213a-4d54-a18f-425f8f4dea4b
https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aWgNx36_460s.jpg
Fat acceptance activist on the news was so fat they had to put her in landscape mode
......
['4d17ee3f-213a-4d54-a18f-425f8f4dea4b', '4d17ee3f-213a-4d54-a18f-425f8f4dea4b', '4d17ee3f-213a-4d54-a18f-425f8f4dea4b']
4d17ee3f-213a-4d54-a18f-425f8f4dea4b
```

EDIT:
code:

```
while True:
    driver.switch_to.window(gag_tab)

    post = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='.post-container a img')


    for post in post:
        post_url = post.get_attribute('src')
        post_title = post.get_attribute('alt')
        #paste the the url  and title in to another site
        time.sleep(20)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 86, in <module>
    post_url = post.get_attribute('src')
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.67)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x009CB8F3+2406643]
    Ordinal0 [0x0095AF31+1945393]
    Ordinal0 [0x0084C748+837448]
    Ordinal0 [0x0084F154+848212]
    Ordinal0 [0x0084F012+847890]
    Ordinal0 [0x0084F98A+850314]
    Ordinal0 [0x008A50C9+1200329]
    Ordinal0 [0x0089427C+1131132]
    Ordinal0 [0x008A4682+1197698]
    Ordinal0 [0x00894096+1130646]
    Ordinal0 [0x0086E636+976438]
    Ordinal0 [0x0086F546+980294]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C39612+2498066]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C2C920+2445600]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A64F2A+579370]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A63D36+574774]
    Ordinal0 [0x00961C0B+1973259]
    Ordinal0 [0x00966688+1992328]
    Ordinal0 [0x00966775+1992565]
    Ordinal0 [0x0096F8D1+2029777]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75B9FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C77A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C77A4E+238]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You forgot to put `search = True` after printing the last post, so it would always skip the loop and print out the first post. But even then, you are not done since `driver.find_element()` always searches for the first element matching your arguments, so it would get stuck in an endless loop because the first post is in the `used` list and would set `search` to `True` endlessly.

Try to use `driver.find_elements()` instead. This will create a list with all the posts, so you can just loop through the list and print each post like that:

```
posts = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.post-container a img')

for post in posts:
    post_url = post.get_attribute('src')
    post_title = post.get_attribute('alt')
    used.append(post.id)
    print(post_url)
    print(post_title)
    print('......')
    print(used)
    print(post.id)
    time.sleep(2)
```

**EDIT:**

Since `driver.find_elements()` will only receive the posts loaded on the website so far, you need to call it again whenever you scroll down the page. That's why I put in a while loop and ignore already printed posts. Regarding the `StaleElementReferenceException` I put a `try-except` Block to ignore elements that are not referenceable anymore. This can happen when you scroll down the site too fast. You import those exceptions like this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
```

Just make sure there are no naming conflicts.

This is my current solution:

```
used = []

while True:
    posts = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.post-container a img')

    for post in posts:
        if not post.id in used:
            try:
                post_url = post.get_attribute('src')
                post_title = post.get_attribute('alt')
            except StaleElementReferenceException or WebDriverException:
                continue

            used.append(post.id)
            print(post_title)
            print(post_url)
            print('__________')
            time.sleep(2)
```

You need to either scroll down the site manually or automatically (Selenium has a function for a driver `execute_script()` where you can execute a scroll command gradually) to load more posts that could be printed.

Comment: Thanks, but then i get this error: if post.id in used:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: @Cypherpunk You can get rid of the whole while loop and try the code above. Then it should work normally.

Comment: @Cypherpunk You don't need the list "used" anymore since this function will already save everything in a list containing the posts. If you replace the whole while loop with this snippet, it should normally print out each element in the list "posts".

Comment: ok but the Bot should always paste one in to another site and then wait 5-10min and then take the next that isnt already used, im not sure but he will take the same image again without a blacklist...

Comment: @Cypherpunk My approach wouldn't use the same image twice, but if you want to wait 5min before printing again, just put `time.sleep(300)`. If you only want to read in elements one by one before printing each of them, you can use your code, but you need to add `search = True` at the end of the inner while loop. Then you would need to find a way to get the next post after the last one because `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='.post-container a img')` will always return you the FIRST post not the next ones.

Comment: I tried it with your code/without the second while loop but i get a error. Watch Edit.

Comment: @Cypherpunk Look at my edit. That should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me. I only have one more problem, there is no reference for `StaleElementReferenceException` and `WebDriverException`

Comment: @Cypherpunk You need to import the exceptions from `selenium.common.exceptions`. For example: `from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException`. Just make sure there is no naming conflict. You might aswell wanna add `NoSuchElementException` to the except-block, you never know. I edited my answer as a reference. If there are any questions about the code, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "post" has no context within which to be relative (value starts with a period). Since there is no description of the structure of the actual webpage, it is hard to determine the correct code you need.

I found these two YouTube clips to be instructive:

- How I use SELENIUM to AUTOMATE the Web with PYTHON. Pt1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUUhvJvs-R4
- How to SCRAPE DYNAMIC websites with Selenium: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTypMlVBFM4